# Asp.net core cannot use NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

When I am trying to do logging from my code, like:

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"{newAccounts.Count()} accounts addded.");
```

or

```
public ClientController(ILogger<ClientController> logger,
...
_logger.LogDebug("debug");
```

I got nothing in my log files. But I could see in my info.txt log file logs of internal asp.net actions, like:

```
2018-05-16 00:30:11.7482|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:63323/Controller/Method
```

My nlog.config looks like:

```
  <targets>
    <target name="fileLogDebug" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/mobileController.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogTrace" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/trace.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogDebug" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/debug.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogInfo" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/info.txt" />
    <target name="err" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/eeeeee.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Trace" writeTo="fileLogTrace" />
    <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="fileLogDebug" />
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="fileLogInfo" />
    <logger name="*" level="Warn" writeTo="fileLogWarn" />
    <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="err" />
    <logger name="*" level="Fatal" writeTo="fileLogSecurity" />
  </rules>
```

NLog init code is:

```
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
    app.AddNLogWeb();
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: Have you tried reading https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2 and upgrading to latest NLog.Web.AspNetCore-nuget ?

Answer (score 1):

Default log level for MS Logging is info.

So set MinimumLevel to Trace to control all from nlog.config:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
        .Build();
```

Example is from official wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Comment: Thats exactly, what I have, but logging still doesnt work.

Comment: Also we had problem with order. Try execute NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config") before adding to logFactory